# Webpack + postcss not purging Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css, postcss

I'm trying to use webpack 5 and tailwind 2. The logs suggest that most things are set up correctly, but no purging is taking place.

I run `NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.prod.js`

I have the following webpack configuration

```
 mode: 'production',
 module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', {
                    loader: "postcss-loader",
                    options: {
                        postcssOptions: {
                            plugins: [
                                require("tailwindcss")("./tailwind.config.js"),
                                require("autoprefixer"),
                            ],
                        },
                    }
                }, "sass-loader"],
            }
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    purge: {
        mode: 'layers',
        layers: [],
        content: ['./src/*.elm', './src/**/*.elm'],
    },
    theme: {
        extend: {}
    },
    variants: {},
    plugins: []
};
```

My production builds are still yielding 4mb bundles which tells me that no purging has taken place.  I think I struggled before and switched to putting the options in a separate postcss.config.js but that shouldn't always be necessary?

In the command line logging I see

```
cacheable modules 4.14 MiB (javascript) 7.64 KiB (asset)
modules by path ./src/ 4.13 MiB (javascript) 7.64 KiB (asset)
modules by path ./src/*.scss 1.34 KiB
  ./src/styles.scss 439 bytes [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/styles.scss 930 bytes [built] [code generated]
./src/index.js + 1 modules 754 bytes [built] [code generated]
./src/Main.elm 159 KiB [built] [code generated]
./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/tailwind.css 3.98 MiB [built] [code generated]
```

Comment: Experiencing the same thing with a wasm-pack plugin project in webpack.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
module.exports = {
    purge: {
        mode: 'layers',
        enabled: true,   // This fixed it for me
        layers: [],
        content: ['./src/*.elm', './src/**/*.elm'],
    },
    theme: {
        extend: {}
    },
    variants: {},
    plugins: []
};
```